# Text Box Rotation Windows Mobile 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, blend

I am using Render Transformation to rotate a text block. Following is the code.

```
</TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      <CompositeTransform Rotation="270"/>
</TextBlock.RenderTransform>
```

Because Render transformation does not recreate UI, Text Block is occupying space in both directions
And the problem is that I can not find Layout transformation in xaml.
So there any what to rotate a textblock with out occupying space horizontally?
thank you very much in advance..

Comment: Why aren't you using RotateTransform with a RenderTransformOrigin instead of CompositeTransform?

Comment: If I understand you, add your textblock in Canvas and change RenderTransformOrigin to 0.5,0.5

Comment: First of all thank you for your answers. I Tried Render Transform Origin But it is only changing point of rotation. For Example If I have 4 text Block (width 200 height 50) horizontally. And I using Render Transform to rotate these text Block 270 degree. After rotation these blocks are occupying height 200 and 200 width on the canvas. even though they are only using(width 200 height 50) vertically.  I want them to occupy only width 200 height 50 vertically so that I can utilize horizontal space.

Comment: Take some screenshots, it may help people understand what is not working.